# Java code has no errors, however compiler runs first class but not the proceeding classes

Tags: java, class

I tried to run this program in Netbeans, but it would only output the area of the rectangle. I was trying to get it to run in sequence after the input and output of rectangle. Was waiting for it to prompt the input for the square but it just stops at the rectangle. Any Suggestions?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class AreaOfRectangle {
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter the length of Rectangle:");
       double length = scanner.nextDouble();

       System.out.println("Enter the width of Rectangle:");
       double width = scanner.nextDouble();


       //Area = length*width;
       double area = length*width;
       System.out.println("Area of Rectangle is:"+area);

   }
}
class SquareAreaDemo {
   public void main extends Thread (String[] args)
   {
       System.out.println("Enter Side of Square:");
       //Capture the user's input
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

       //Storing the captured value in a variable
       double side = scanner.nextDouble();
       //Area of Square = side*side
       double area = side*side; 

       System.out.println("Area of Square is: "+area);

   }
}
class AreaTriangleDemo {
   public void main(String args[]) {   
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the width of the Triangle:");
      double base = scanner.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter the height of the Triangle:");
      double height = scanner.nextDouble();

      //Area = (width*height)/2
      double area = (base* height)/2;
      System.out.println("Area of Triangle is: " + area);      
   }
}
```

Comment: When you start a Java program, you tell Java which class to execute, it finds **the** main method in **that** class, and executes it. Creating 3 separate classes with 3 separate main methods allows executing 3 separate programs, but not one program doing 3 different things sequentially. You should have a single main method calling three separate non-main methods sequentially instead.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html.

Comment: This `public void main extends Thread (String[] args)` shouldn't compile. I'm guessing that you copied it wrong, and ask that you take care to copy code as carefully as possible. No sense in confusing us needlessly.

Comment: Also, don't equate no compilation errors with "no errors". Your program is not running as you expect it, and so it has *logical* errors, errors that can be *much* harder to debug than compilation errors.

Comment: Noted! Thank you for the help! I mistakenly copied the code with the extend thread in it. I was just trying it out at the time I copied and pasted. Thank you for the tips!